# Issue connecting to MariaDB with mariaex

Tags: mariadb, elixir

I'm using `mariaex` version `0.8.4` to connect on a MariaDB server version `10.10` from an Elixir `1.15.7` web application (not Phoenix, but Plug-based)

The configuration file looks like this:

```
config :myapp, db: [
  pool: DBConnection.Poolboy,
  pool_size: 10,
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  database: "myapp_db",
  user: "user",
  password: "pass"
]
```

and the DB is started in `application.ex` like this

```
# ...

    db_conf =
      Application.get_env(:alaaarmo, :db)
      |> Keyword.put(:name, DB)
    
    children = [
      {Mariaex, db_conf},
      {Bandit, http_conf}
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Alaaarmo.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

Now when the application starts, I get and endless number of lines stating that:

```
15:54:23.941 [error] Mariaex.Protocol (#PID<0.237.0>) failed to connect: 
** (Mariaex.Error) (1045): Access denied for user 'maurycy'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

(`maurycy` being my system username)

When I try to connect from a terminal with the following command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user --password=pass myapp_db
```

all goes fine.

Comment: It's not `user`, but `username` that is the user name to be sent to the DB...

Comment: "The configuration file looks like this: ....host: "127.0.0.1", .... " , "Access denied for user 'maurycy'@'172.17.0.1'.......   Is 127.17.0.1 not a **different** ip address ?

Comment: @Luuk No. In the configuration I defined `user` instead of `username`... RTFM! I believe that when the driver can't connect with what is provided in the configuration, it tries with the system credentials. So now I don't have any error at startup, but when I send a query,, whatever it is, for exemple `Mariaex.query!(DB, "CREATE TABLE test1 (id serial, title text)")`, I get: `** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :invalid_message.exception/1 is undefined (module :invalid_message is not available)
    :invalid_message.exception([])`

Comment: ! second...... I only thought of that 1 second.... that your usernames are different.. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to be remembered to that fact that our (the simple user who is trying to help your) time is valuable....